# Unable to locate package libssl-dev

Tags: command-line

I got this error while try to implement the aes c program in `openssl` please help me to solve this problem :

```
fatal error: openssl/aes.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/aes.h>
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: That are two question. One in the title and one in the question.

Answer (score 3):

The missing file is part of the package `libssl-dev`. Therefore install it via

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```